# What are possible causes of Multiple ID-statement Exception in Sesame?

Tags: sesame, openrdf

I would like to know what are possible causes that can rise the following Exception ?

```
org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException: Multiple ID-statements for repository ID test_3
```

It rises when i try to query the `test_3` repository. Another fact is that after that there is two repository with the same name displayed in my web page http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/NONE/repositories

any help is welcome !

**EDIT**

I'm using Sesame 2.7.7

**EDIT 2**

Providing more details about the code which cause the Exception

code

public void connectToRepository(){

```
    RepositoryConnection connection;

    RemoteRepositoryManager repositoryManager = new RemoteRepositoryManager("http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/"); 

    try {

        repositoryManager.initialize();

        SailImplConfig backendConfig = new NativeStoreConfig("spoc,sopc,posc,psoc,ospc,opsc");

        RepositoryImplConfig repositoryTypeSpec = new SailRepositoryConfig(backendConfig);

        RepositoryConfig repConfig = new RepositoryConfig(repositoryID, repositoryTypeSpec);

        repositoryManager.addRepositoryConfig(repConfig);

        Repository myRepository = repositoryManager.getRepository(repositoryID);

        myRepository.initialize();

        connection = myRepository.getConnection();

    } 

    catch (RepositoryException | RepositoryConfigException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Exception is cause by the following line in the code:

```
repositoryManager.addRepositoryConfig(repConfig);
```

Here are details

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.openrdf.rio.DatatypeHandlerRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Custom NTriples/NQuads Parser
Custom NTriples/NQuads Parser
org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException: Multiple ID-statements for repository ID 10m7_m
at org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigUtil.getIDStatement(RepositoryConfigUtil.java:269)
at org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigUtil.hasRepositoryConfig(RepositoryConfigUtil.java:91)
at org.openrdf.repository.manager.RemoteRepositoryManager.createRepository(RemoteRepositoryManager.java:174)
at org.openrdf.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.getRepository(RepositoryManager.java:376)
at soctrace.repositories.OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.connectToRepository(OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.java:123)
at soctrace.repositories.OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.queryInRepository(OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.java:150)
at soctrace.views.Main.main(Main.java:692)
[sesame in memory] connection to repository 10m7_m done , 444, ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at soctrace.repositories.OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.runQuery(OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.java:250)
at soctrace.repositories.OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.queryInRepository(OLDSesameRepositoryManagement.java:155)
at soctrace.views.Main.main(Main.java:692)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates a new repository (by adding a new repository configuration to the repository manager) *every* time you execute the `connectToRepository()` method. Since you use the exact same repository configuration (*including* the actual id of the repository) every time, naturally this causes an error the second time you execute it: you are trying to add a repository with an id that already exists.

You should rewrite your code to make sure that it *only* tries to create the repository when a repository with that id doesn't exist yet - if it already exists, it should just use the existing one.